# C#6 null-conditional operator - as a code toggler?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

I already know that the  null-conditional operator  [can be used to test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) for null before performing a member access.

for example :

```
 int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null 
 Customer first = customers?[0];
```

If `customers` is null in  `customers?.Length`  , then `customers?.Length`  will return null and that `null` will be in `int? length  = ...` variable

I also know that it can be [used](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/cs6/#2) for a single atomic operation of method invocation in a multithreaded environment :

```
public void OnFoo()
{
    Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

**But**

AFAIU - if `Foo` is `null` then

```
 Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Is also `null`

And so we're left with

```
public void OnFoo()
{
    null; //compilation error
}
```

And so I ask :

**Question**

it seems that the  null-conditional operator   is not only for testing null and if there is , then it moves on deeper :  `x?.y?.c?.d`  -

but it is also act like code toggle :

Like this:

```
  public void OnFoo()
    {
        Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Let's assume Foo =null;
    }
```

Becomes

```
  public void OnFoo()
    {

    }
```

Am I right? I didn't find any documentation to that aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null conditional operator is an operator which results in an *expression* - it's not a *statement*.

Your logic about `Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)` being equivalent to `null` doesn't really hold, as it seems to assume a sort of "template replacement" which doesn't apply.

The type of the expression

```
Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)
```

is nothing, because `Invoke` has a `void` return type. You can't write:

```
// Invalid
var result = Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

This is just like in 7.6.5 of the C# 5 specification:

> The result of evaluating an invocation-expression is classified as follows:
>
> - If the invocation-expression invokes a method or delegate that returns `void`, the result is nothing. An expression that is classified as nothing is permitted only in the context of a statement-expression (§8.6) or as the body of a lambda-expression (§7.15). Otherwise a binding-time error occurs.
> - Otherwise, the result is a value of the type returned by the method or delegate.

A member invocation can use a null conditional operator, at which point the invocation is only performed when the primary expression evaluates to a non-null value. The result of an invocation expression involving a null conditional operator is the same as it would be with a regular `.` operator, except that if the result would be a non-nullable value type, the result with the null conditional operator is the corresponding nullable value type.

All of this will be put a lot more precisely when the C# 6 specification comes out, of course - but I don't know when that will be. (I don't *think* there's a C# 6 spec at the moment. I'm sure there's one internally in MS, but not a public one. As the ECMA standardization process is getting closer for standardizing C# 5, that could potentially impact the release process for C# 6.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. But  : _[If you can print it, or assign it to a variable, it’s an expression. If you can’t, it’s a statement](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-an-expression-in-Python)._ . And since I cant assign it to a variable via : `var result = Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` - then according tot he link , it is a statement. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's about Python, not C#, and I suspect it's still an over-simplification. Your `var result = ...;` doesn't compile because `Invoke` returns `void`... I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: Jon - [Am I dreaming](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.pdf?raw=true)? See page 188

Comment: @RoyiNamir: From the repo readme: "Microsoft has not yet released an official copy of the C#6 spec. This is an unofficial draft. When Microsoft does release its official copy, before end 2016 at the latest, then this current repository will be deleted. That's because I wouldn't want to have two copies of the C#6 spec floating around."

Comment: Yes , but it's still something .

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Sure. Just not an official C# 6 specification. Is there anything within that that you think contradicts my answer?

Comment: No:-) I didn't say that.  I was happy to see the "sort of" spec for null-conditional operator. https://i.imgur.com/oVObTl3.jpg , and I shared it with you.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well, you did say "Am I dreaming?" which suggests a contradiction - that's why I was looking for some inaccuracy in what I'd said.